# Is it allowed to static_cast between different types of const?

Tags: c++

I have rarely seen static_cast between top level const so far.
Recently I had to use static_cast to display address of a pointer to const object and I come out with this question:
Is it allowed to static_cast between different types of const?

It passed compilation using gcc 4.7. But I am just asking here to confirm it is not UB. Thanks.

```
  const int a = 42; // test case 1, const obj
  const double b = static_cast<const double>(a);
  cout << b << endl;


  const int c = 0; // test case 2, pointer to const obj
  cout << static_cast<const void*>(&c) << endl;
```

Comment: Case 2 is not casting top level const; I thought you were going to ask about `static_cast<int>(a)`  , which I think is legal (it doesn't count as "casting away constness")

Comment: @MattMcNabb Thanks. I just edited that. In fact I meant to check conversion between pointer to const obj.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [expr.static.cast]

> [...] The static_cast operator shall not cast away constness

It's perfectly fine to *add* `const` using `static_cast`, then again you don't need to in your test case

```
const int a = 42; // test case 1, const obj
const double b = static_cast<double>(a); // Works just as well.
const double b = a; // Of course this is fine too
```

I suppose one of the few times you'd want to add `const` with `static_cast` would be to explicitly call an overloaded function

```
void foo(int*) { }
void foo(int const*) { }

int main()
{
  int a = 42;

  foo(&a);
  foo(static_cast<int const*>(&a));
}
```

Although with properly designed code you shouldn't really need to do this.